# Transparent Derivable Nested Types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I kind of found a solution for this, but I feel its rather hacky and leaves a lot more to be desired from the Intellisense that is generated for it.

I'd like to create a generic type A, that contains a reference to another generic type B (but not any data for that type), such that I can derive type B from type A via a type transformation function. I'd also like to use that type derivation mechanism to create a type guard for type B with only type A as the type input.

## Full code example ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhCgAIUglBTADgJ3gZ3gOwC5sgQ0lTQFcAbbSAewDMDMCBjbASysyhGHGwE9F4kAILM2mBKQoAeKMNHsAcvgC2g+AA9sWACZ402ZC0wBzSAF5I+wyYA0sieWwAFZFUR4LAbwC+4AHzmkJ6yfAIAXHKsiirwdpBE6I4RBiSx4N6QAGRwiRQubmgA3ODgoBDQOSjoWLj0kWI2kABGJJT4ZGhUkIzs2PhGeADuLNgAFkaQI5BjgqGCtJPYAOR4xI6c3HP17DLxIlGYSqqQGlqYupYGRqYWVteNwNzx+e6BPnE5ks6ur16+AV4Qvx4BF9mIjml4msKAB+CIkc7wGhGeDaD4AfXRAEkAOIKADysAAouiACL49EEgAq6IAykSaeiHBQqcC4dtxLlsFIwdFVI1md8Cn47Blsi8iiUypxIKyBJBjCR8MhtJAaFRkARLAJGCxkYwmAcNuAaAj5AwWGheZgeSdNDo8Na-AAKfDmiGggDaSzmSwAuo03QcIggeiqpHdbJAEQBrTBUQaYPwASgiQbEk0dQVkesgrvNADotmYS4bwTEstl0+wC9DKCWLAjtEiUdpk9n4lD4NgSMgGCl4MV4r4uz2+2r2hhir5SmAZaT4IYAG6zUaCQXTYFq1zKOrWzcCY1bQUAMR31t2wjtZwu1v8gQUinIZHwTTI8B53sxuIJxLJFOpOkGUxQU5Xgf0-GKWdyhgMCFSVFU1Q1LU0B1PUWANasGDrPMml4Dlk2NU1MHNTNrUFW1TgdDkXSwj1hG9X0AwSL4Q3gMNtAjK4o1jeNExTCIcMtT5HDPKhlAvIQAmCeJc2dOsiy3Bsyz5QRMmyBS63bGTO1QMd+2QVIh0gEcEn0icOkHdIpW4R5ZXQSgAGEqGbUpNi3JQlxYYx8C0fcLAvWQ7Ihag6Cw2QlkwfAvJ8rQlg+OynGVFQ8AWcL4h0+JEF80YIkjYxZG8BLgEgJLkBS0KWMcSr0o7TtSEYRh0DQCImioKh33wDhh38EotixEjUFUHBnIRLRkH8jlL2Cis0vNCKjEYIaalGnBF3ioKSrKiq5qNDLZHiJd2lSKkqCEbRtAiTASGUJpF0K4rSuS5RUroHDdrEWRMsgTB4EGAA1Y6QR+m67uQQrercyBHNQXzBEIZQqEYGNIE87y4etRoWkoRwWGUOGyHw-A0AwZBKCmYmcg4rjrGMRpeITJMoc6SBBkERguujDBpjXMjSK2RVlVVbAumbcblBRRZVngdoD3gAtwB6TB9BUzA2Op-L6cwONGYBOq5giSLovRuKPmysZDdGbBsEQMJHmMdrjHfAsemUDaMkptHYvga0oLky0Ly9jHzRdI2Yrh+LVeTbTZCVzpnbIKhjGdJYg780jzdyyBI6wgtM+TQpIDsrDMx+hMtTTn35oyeBLMmOhnQD80pAGpb4GG7BVvGp0U8W5aRqoMb1sDc1o7quOOvlxPk6WVv+87we1om0ijrIE6zouw2R4OAtV-X8622nGzodhrQtUR5HUeN739zrLHWmjCg8YJomScXcm2jwUMNU4zXo21viTM7IszZt0TmJBuYzD5gcDcAsELC1Ft2RcEtfpSwSLLOYCs46UDrOrH+NN7j-x1vxN4QJwjZyiuHU2shcHTEMpCSwJBGrNWSPQ0UBAv5cjEhJZulcnR+wbk3GBXIpB8JDinShJtwKNC0jHeIE8E5JxTmIg4VUKBbzUdgAsDUmokwLkXEqABNfAvAZFclLnxDhV8qFV1UXWdIJw67+ytOaCic924rUXt3cRSw+4eIHkPZAkdZHj3YPHKeSjZ6DX8QvQJ+5foAyBhohSCTAZr3gAXayQA))

```
/**
 * Represents a result of an action
 */
type ActionResult<
  ActionName extends string = string,
  ResultProps = {}
> = {
  type: ActionName,
  result: true,
} & ResultProps;

/**
 * Represents an Action, but also contains within it the type of it's result
 */
type Action<
  ActionName extends string = string,
  Props = {},
  ResultProps = {}
> = {
  type: ActionName,
  result?: undefined,
  __IGNORE_DO_NOT_SET__ResultType?: ActionResult<ActionName, ResultProps>,
} & Props;

/**
 * Type guard for a specific action
 */
function isAction<A extends Action>(actionName: A['type'], action: Record<string, unknown>): action is A {
  if (action.type === actionName && action.result === undefined) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

/**
 * Derive the Result type from an Action type
 */
type ResultFromAction<
  A extends Action
> = NonNullable<A['__IGNORE_DO_NOT_SET__ResultType']>;

/**
 * Type guard for a specific action result (by Action)
 */
function isActionResult<A extends Action>(actionName: A['type'], result: Record<string, unknown>): result is ResultFromAction<A> {
  if (result.type === actionName && result.result) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

//
// Test Code
//
type NavigateAction = Action<
  // Name of action
  'navigate',
  // Params of action
  {
    path: string
  },
  // Params of result of action
  {
    success: boolean
  }
>

type IncrementCounterAction = Action<
  // Name of action
  'incrementCounter',
  // Params of action
  {
    valueToAdd: number
  },
  // Params of result of action
  {
    newValue: number
  }
>

// Create a mock NavigateAction, but ultimately assert it as Record<string, unknown>
// so we can use the isAction type guard to determine its real type.
const action: Record<string, unknown> = {
  type: 'navigate',
  path: 'http://google.com',
} as NavigateAction;

if (isAction<NavigateAction>('navigate', action)) {
  console.log('NavigateAction path: ', action.path); // action is now a NavigateAction
} else if (isAction<IncrementCounterAction>('incrementCounter', action)) {
  console.log('IncrementCounterAction valueToAdd: ', action.valueToAdd);
}

// Create a mock NavigateAction result, but ultimately assert it as Record<string, unknown>
// so we can use the isActionResult type guard to determine its real type.
const result: Record<string, unknown> = {
  type: 'navigate',
  result: true,
  success: true,
} as ResultFromAction<NavigateAction>;

if (isActionResult<NavigateAction>('navigate', result)) {
  console.log('NavigateAction result: ', result.success); // Yay, result is now as NavigateAction result
} else if (isActionResult<IncrementCounterAction>('incrementCounter', result)) {
  console.log('IncrementCounterAction newValue: ', result.newValue);
}
```

## Breakdown

You can see from the above example that I can create discrete Action types that each contain their own Action "result types" as an optional property aptly named **__IGNORE_DO_NOT_SET__ResultType** (named because we just want to store a reference to the type, and do NOT want the data for the result type to be placed into the outer Action type).

```
type Action<
  ActionName extends string = string,
  Props = {},
  ResultProps = {}
> = {
  type: ActionName,
  result?: undefined,
  __IGNORE_DO_NOT_SET__ResultType?: ActionResult<ActionName, ResultProps>,
} & Props;
```

The result type can then be extracted from any Action type using a combination of accessing the property with square brackets and wrapping that in a NonNullable<> in order to remove the "optional-ness" from it:

```
type ResultFromAction<
  A extends Action
> = NonNullable<A['__IGNORE_DO_NOT_SET__ResultType']>;
```

And type guard functions are then easily constructed for both the Action and the Action's result (with only the Action as the generic type input of both functions)

```
function isAction<A extends Action>(actionName: A['type'], action: Record<string, unknown>): action is A {
  if (action.type === actionName && action.result === undefined) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function isActionResult<A extends Action>(actionName: A['type'], result: Record<string, unknown>): result is ResultFromAction<A> {
  if (result.type === actionName && result.result) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

And if you look closely at the Test Code toward the bottom you can see how this is used to properly construct Action types that always have a nested result type, and how the type guards & ResultFromAction are put to use and very nicely allow for the concept of just using the Action type in order to derive the result type:

```
type NavigateAction = Action<
  // Name of action
  'navigate',
  // Params of action
  {
    path: string
  },
  // Params of result of action
  {
    success: boolean
  }
>

type IncrementCounterAction = Action<
  // Name of action
  'incrementCounter',
  // Params of action
  {
    valueToAdd: number
  },
  // Params of result of action
  {
    newValue: number
  }
>

// Create a mock NavigateAction, but ultimately assert it as Record<string, unknown>
// so we can use the isAction type guard to determine its real type.
const action: Record<string, unknown> = {
  type: 'navigate',
  path: 'http://google.com',
} as NavigateAction;

if (isAction<NavigateAction>('navigate', action)) {
  console.log('NavigateAction path: ', action.path); // action is now a NavigateAction
} else if (isAction<IncrementCounterAction>('incrementCounter', action)) {
  console.log('IncrementCounterAction valueToAdd: ', action.valueToAdd);
}

// Create a mock NavigateAction result, but ultimately assert it as Record<string, unknown>
// so we can use the isActionResult type guard to determine its real type.
const result: Record<string, unknown> = {
  type: 'navigate',
  result: true,
  success: true,
} as ResultFromAction<NavigateAction>;

if (isActionResult<NavigateAction>('navigate', result)) {
  console.log('NavigateAction result: ', result.success); // Yay, result is now as NavigateAction result
} else if (isActionResult<IncrementCounterAction>('incrementCounter', result)) {
  console.log('IncrementCounterAction newValue: ', result.newValue);
}
```

## Question

Is there a way to do this so that the nested type is "transparent" and only accessible from a type context? It's a bummer IMO to see **__IGNORE_DO_NOT_SET__ResultType** (regardless of the name) in the Intellisense list as it only screams to how much this is a *hack* vs a best practice.

[image: Intellisense list of an Action value containing __IGNORE_DO_NOT_SET__ResultType]

P.S. I really don't know the best terminology to describe what I'm trying to achieve here, but if anyone else knows and can let me know I will update the title and my description.

Comment: This may be similar to [type brands](https://medium.com/@KevinBGreene/surviving-the-typescript-ecosystem-branding-and-type-tagging-6cf6e516523d)?

Comment: TypeScript's type system is all about *structure*, but you're looking for a type that depends on another type in a non-structural way.  So everything I can think of is just a workaround (and similar to a phantom property) *unless* you can think of an actual structural way an `Action<A, P, R>` should depend on `R`.  It certainly seems like some code somewhere should be able to turn an `Action<A, P, R>` into an `R` or a `Promise<R>` or a `Promise<R | undefined>` or something.  Maybe there should be a method on `Action` that encapsulates this?

Comment: You really want [microsoft/TypeScript#33290](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33290) but this never made it into the language.  So I don't know of any surefire way to make something depend on a type without having a property of that type, or a method which accepts or returns that type, etc.

Comment: @AlexWayne I suppose the phantom property used is sort of a brand but not really used here specifically for that purpose
@jcalz Thanks (again). Definitely not interested in adding a function to Action, as I don't want any implementation to exist on this type, nor do I really know what the function would do other than hold the type. That `tag type` PR looks interesting, though I don't see an example in that PR that does something similar to what I'm doing here with an extractable nested type. So it's hard to say if that feature would even enable this type of thing without the phantom property.